# HTML/CSS: Placing a DIV after a fixed DIV

Tags: html, css

I try to use a fixed div for a navigation header.

Jumping to the desired areas works well but the content-div starts at the very top.

How can I make it start AFTER the navi-div?

It should be very simple and without JS or big CSS.

```html
<div style="position: fixed; width: 100%; top: 0; background: white; border: 1px solid blue; height: 30px; margin: 10px;">
<a href="#aaa">gotoA</a>
<a href="#bbb">gotoB</a>
<a href="#ccc">gotoC</a>
</div>


 <div id="aaa" style="background: yellow;">
 a*<br>
 a1<br>
 a2<br>
 a3</br>
 a4</br>
 a5</br>
 a6</br>
 a7</br>
 a8</br>
 a</br>
 a</br>
 a</br>
 a</br>
 a</br>
 a</br>
 a</br>
 a</br>
 a</br>
 a</br>
 a</br>
 a</br>
 a</br>
 a</br>
 a</br>
 a</br>
 a</br>
 a</br>
 a</br>
 a</br>
 a</br>
 a</br>
 a</br>
 a</br>
 a</br>
 a</br>
 a</br>
 a</br>
 a</br>
 a</br>
 a</br>
 a</br>
 a</br>
 a</br>
 a</br>
 a</br>
 a</br>
 a</br>
 a</br>
 a</br>
 a</br>
 a</br>
 a</br>
 a</br>
 a</br>
 a+</br>
 </div>

 <div id="bbb" style="background: orange;">
 b*</br>
 b1</br>
 b2</br>
 b3</br>
 b4</br>
 b5</br>
 b6</br>
 b7</br>
 b8</br>
 b</br>
 b</br>
 b</br>
 b</br>
 b</br>
 b</br>
 b</br>
 b</br>
 b</br>
 b</br>
 b</br>
 b</br>
 b</br>
 b</br>
 b</br>
 b</br>
 b</br>
 b</br>
 b</br>
 b</br>
 b</br>
 b</br>
 b</br>
 b</br>
 b</br>
 b</br>
 b</br>
 b</br>
 b</br>
 b</br>
 b</br>
 b</br>
 b</br>
 b</br>
 b</br>
 b</br>
 b</br>
 b</br>
 b+</br>
 </div>

 <div id="ccc" style="background: lime;">
 c*</br>
 c1</br>
 c2</br>
 c3</br>
 c4</br>
 c5</br>
 c6</br>
 c7</br>
 c8</br>
 c</br>
 c</br>
 c</br>
 c</br>
 c</br>
 c</br>
 c</br>
 c</br>
 c</br>
 c</br>
 c</br>
 c</br>
 c</br>
 c</br>
 c</br>
 c</br>
 c</br>
 c</br>
 c</br>
 c</br>
 c</br>
 c</br>
 c</br>
 c</br>
 c</br>
 c</br>
 c</br>
 c</br>
 c</br>
 c</br>
 c</br>
 c</br>
 c</br>
 c</br>
 c</br>
 c</br>
 c</br>
 c</br>
 c</br>
 c</br>
 c</br>
 c</br>
 c</br>
 c</br>
 c</br>
 c</br>
 c</br>
 c</br>
 c</br>
 c</br>
 c+</br>
 </div>
```

I but a sample here:

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j4hxLt1d/)

Comment: `margin-top: 30px` (or 40, since you have 10px margin on the fixed div already)

Comment: Mover your content to fixed element. https://jsfiddle.net/71ck9bqn/

Comment: I tried margin-top but it did not work. I places it into the style-attribute of every content-div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `padding-top` to the first content div, or a wrapper of all content divs.

```html
<div style="position: fixed; width: 100%; top: 0; background: white; border: 1px solid blue; height: 30px; margin: 10px;">
  <a href="#aaa">gotoA</a>
  <a href="#bbb">gotoB</a>
  <a href="#ccc">gotoC</a>
</div>


<div id="aaa" style="background: yellow; padding-top: 50px">a*<br>a1<br>a2<br>a3<br>a4<br>a5<br>a6<br>a7<br>a8<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>
a+<br></div>

<div id="bbb" style="background: orange;">b*<br>b1<br>b2<br>b3<br>b4<br>b5<br>b6<br>b7<br>b8<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b+<br></div>

<div id="ccc" style="background: lime;">c*<br>c1<br>c2<br>c3<br>c4<br>c5<br>c6<br>c7<br>c8<br>c<br>c<br>c<br>c<br>c<br>c<br>c<br>c<br>c<br>c<br>c<br>c<br>c<br>c<br>c<br>c<br>c<br>c<br>c<br>c<br>c<br>c<br>c<br>c<br>c<br>c<br>c<br>c<br>c<br>c<br>c<br>c<br>c<br>c<br>c<br>c<br>c<br>c<br>c<br>c<br>c<br>c<br>c<br>c<br>c<br>c<br>c<br>c<br>c<br>c<br>c+<br></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the following example

```css
#aaa {
  background: yellow;
  margin-top: calc(var(--menu-height) + (2 * var(--menu-margin))); /* 2 * margin for top and bot */
}

#bbb {
  background: orange;
}

#ccc {
  background: lime;
}

.menu {
  position: fixed; 
  width: 100%; 
  top: 0; 
  background: white; 
  border: 1px solid blue; 
  height: var(--menu-height); 
  margin: var(--menu-margin);  
}

:root {
  --menu-height: 30px;
  --menu-margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
<a href="#aaa">gotoA</a>
<a href="#bbb">gotoB</a>
<a href="#ccc">gotoC</a>
</div>


 <div id="aaa">
 a*<br>
 a1<br>
 a2<br>
 a3</br>
 a4</br>
 a5</br>
 a6</br>
 a7</br>
 a8</br>
 a</br>
 a</br>
 a</br>
 a</br>
 a</br>
 a</br>
 a</br>
 a</br>
 a</br>
 a</br>
 a</br>
 a</br>
 a</br>
 a</br>
 a</br>
 a</br>
 a</br>
 a</br>
 a</br>
 a</br>
 a</br>
 a</br>
 a</br>
 a</br>
 a</br>
 a</br>
 a</br>
 a</br>
 a</br>
 a</br>
 a</br>
 a</br>
 a</br>
 a</br>
 a</br>
 a</br>
 a</br>
 a</br>
 a</br>
 a</br>
 a</br>
 a</br>
 a</br>
 a</br>
 a</br>
 a+</br>
 </div>

 <div id="bbb">
 b*</br>
 b1</br>
 b2</br>
 b3</br>
 b4</br>
 b5</br>
 b6</br>
 b7</br>
 b8</br>
 b</br>
 b</br>
 b</br>
 b</br>
 b</br>
 b</br>
 b</br>
 b</br>
 b</br>
 b</br>
 b</br>
 b</br>
 b</br>
 b</br>
 b</br>
 b</br>
 b</br>
 b</br>
 b</br>
 b</br>
 b</br>
 b</br>
 b</br>
 b</br>
 b</br>
 b</br>
 b</br>
 b</br>
 b</br>
 b</br>
 b</br>
 b</br>
 b</br>
 b</br>
 b</br>
 b</br>
 b</br>
 b</br>
 b+</br>
 </div>

 <div id="ccc">
 c*</br>
 c1</br>
 c2</br>
 c3</br>
 c4</br>
 c5</br>
 c6</br>
 c7</br>
 c8</br>
 c</br>
 c</br>
 c</br>
 c</br>
 c</br>
 c</br>
 c</br>
 c</br>
 c</br>
 c</br>
 c</br>
 c</br>
 c</br>
 c</br>
 c</br>
 c</br>
 c</br>
 c</br>
 c</br>
 c</br>
 c</br>
 c</br>
 c</br>
 c</br>
 c</br>
 c</br>
 c</br>
 c</br>
 c</br>
 c</br>
 c</br>
 c</br>
 c</br>
 c</br>
 c</br>
 c</br>
 c</br>
 c</br>
 c</br>
 c</br>
 c</br>
 c</br>
 c</br>
 c</br>
 c</br>
 c</br>
 c</br>
 c</br>
 c</br>
 c</br>
 c+</br>
 </div>
```